# How to change values of an array inside a class

Tags: java

I have a question about my code.

```
class Zillion
{
    private int[] d;
    public Zillion(int size)
    {
        d = new int[size];
    }
    public void timesTen()
    {
       for(int i = 0; i<d.length;i++)
       {
           d[i] = d[i + 1];
       }
       d[d.length]=0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String num;
        num= "";
        for(int i = 0; i<d.length; i++)
        {
            num = num + d[i];
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Here in my class Zillion, I am trying to multiply a number that is represent by an array by 10. So what I did was I move the elements at each index to the left and change the value at the last index to 0. For instance,

### 0 1 4 8 will be come 1 4 8 0.

I am not sure whether my logic will work but that was my first start.
First, I am trying to change the values at each index of the array with an assigned size and here is my driver file.

```
class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Zillion z = new Zillion(5);
        System.out.println(z);  //  00000  


       for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j += 1)
        {
          z[j]=j;
        }
        System.out.println(z);  

    }
}
```

However, Java throws me an error and says: **"Error:(32, 14) java: array required, but Zillion found"**. 
I took C++ and I believe I could change array values like z[j] = j but I guess it is different in Java.
Is there a way I can change the values of the specific index I want? The reason why I used the for loop is because I could not think of any method that I can use to assign the values at each index I want. Is that possible that in the Driver file I create an array, say, 0148 and call my "timesTen" method to give me what I want?
Thank you!

Comment: You need an accessor in your class to the array: int[] getD() { return this.d; }  and then: z.getD()[j] = j  should work.  this is really a bad way to assign values to a member variable, consider putting the whole loop as a member function.

Comment: This d[d.length] = 0; should be d[d.length - 1] = 0;

Comment: `z` is an instance of the class `Zillion` and not an array

Comment: In the `timesTen` method, I think the `for` condition should be `i<d.length-1`, otherwise `d[i+1]` raises an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone! I just started to pick up Java three days ago by myself.

Comment: OMG I MADE IT WORK YAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the array d of zillion class using a gettor method.

public   getArray(){ return d;}

Instead of z[j]=j; you need to use z.getArray()[j] = j

Also your timesTen method will cause arrayindex out of bounds exception in the line 
   d[d.length]=0;

Java array is not dynamically growing so, Index should be lesser than array size.

Answer (score 0):

You can't index a class, only arrays.

Define a method in Zillion

```
class Zillion {

    public void set(int index, int value) {
        // TODO implement
    } 
 }
```

In your loop, call `z.set(j,  j)`

Note: `j <= 5` will cause an out of bound exception

Comment: OMG I MADE IT WORK.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe I could change array values like z[j] = j

You could - if `z` would be an array! But, as the error message also states, it is an object of type `Zillion`:

> ```
> Zillion z = new Zillion(5);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using instance z of Zillion class, use array instead of it.

```
//Create getter method in Zillion Class
public int[] getD() {
        return d;
    }

//And access that array in Driver Class
int[] array = z.getD();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j += 1) {
            array[j] = j;
        }
```

Comment: I fixed that perfectly and my print out is this **"[I@76fb509a
"**.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, you are going to face an

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

because of the statement `d[d.length] = 0;` in your timesTen() implementation. You have to replace that line with:

```
d[d.length-1] = 0;
```

This is not an answer to your question, because you have already received valuable ones, but I hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your response. However, when I fixed my code, my print out is this **[I@76fb509a**

Comment: I am not able to see your output.